# Multiline comment with formatting from existing element with child elements

Tags: xml, powershell

I have some XML with elements in this format...

```
<UninstallProgram id="Autodesk Genuine Service">
    <Search>Autodesk Genuine Service</Search>
    <Executable>msiexec.exe</Executable>
    <Arguments>/x [Task~GUID] /quiet /norestart</Arguments>
</UninstallProgram>
```

and I have a need to remark some of them out, but I specifically want to remark them in a nice, readable format, so...

```
<!--<UninstallProgram id="Autodesk Genuine Service">
    <Search>Autodesk Genuine Service</Search>
    <Executable>msiexec.exe</Executable>
    <Arguments>/x [Task~GUID] /quiet /norestart</Arguments>
</UninstallProgram>-->
```

The snippet of code doing the remarking now is...

```
if ($id -in $removedIds) {
    $comment = $existingXml.CreateComment(($source.OuterXml))
    $existingXml.DocumentElement.AppendChild($comment)
}
```

which produces a single line comment. When I clone and append an element it is formatted correctly, so I don't think it's an XmlReaderSettings issue. Am I on the right track, and just need a slightly different approach, or is this actually not possible? I would happily just take the main element and loose the child elements if I have to, but I would prefer the whole thing as shown I think.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#Sample XML

[XML]$xml = '<UninstallProgram id="Autodesk Genuine Service">
    <Search>Autodesk Genuine Service</Search>
    <Executable>msiexec.exe</Executable>
    <Arguments>/x [Task~GUID] /quiet /norestart</Arguments>
</UninstallProgram>'


$element = $xml.UninstallProgram # Replace this with the correct element
$comment = $xml.CreateComment($element.OuterXml)
$xml.InsertAfter($comment, $element)
$xml.RemoveChild($element)
```

Your results should be:

```
<!--<UninstallProgram id="Autodesk Genuine Service">
    <Search>Autodesk Genuine Service</Search>
    <Executable>msiexec.exe</Executable>
    <Arguments>/x [Task~GUID] /quiet /norestart</Arguments>
</UninstallProgram>-->
```